# For loop not looping and can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

So I'm doing some programming exercises and I got stuck on this one.  It's a simple search for the `E`'s in a phrase . I don't get why the `for` dosen't loop, and the result just goes to the confirm that it did not find any `E`'s in my phrase. Can anyone see anything wrong with my `for` loop?

```
/*
 * Function that counts E's in a user-enter'd phrase
 **/
function countE() {
  var phrase = prompt("Which phrase would you lke to examine ?");
  if( typeof(phrase) != "string" ) {
    alert("That is not a valid entry!");
    return false;
  }  else {
    for(var eCount = 0; eCount < phrase.length; eCount++) {
      if( phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'E' || phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'e' ) {
        alert("There are " + eCount + " E's in \"" + phrase + "\".");
        return true;
      } else {
        var report = confirm("I did not find any E's in your phrase. Would you like to try again?");
        if(report == true) {
          return countE();
        } else {
          alert("Ok maybe next time!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

countE();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning for the first character no matter what. Further, you're reporting the position in the string, not the number of e's.

This should get you started in the right direction:

```
    var eCount = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {

        if( phrase.charAt(i) == 'E' || phrase.charAt(i) == 'e' ) {

            eCount++;

        }
    }

        if( eCount > 0 ) {

            alert("There are " + eCount + " E's in \"" + phrase + "\".");
            return true;

        } else {
            var report = confirm("I did not find any E's in your phrase. Would you like to try again?");

            if(report == true) {

                return countE();

            } else {

                alert("Ok maybe next time!");

                return false;
            }
        }
```

I removed the `return` statements from the loop (which were causing it to stop), and moved the report of the count to after the loop completes. I also created a separate variable for the count, replacing `eCount` with `i` for the loop.

Comment: eCount in condition in for loop still needs changing to i

Comment: return CountE() needs to be return eCount

Comment: Ok so tnx man your code works , actually works. The only problem now is that it dose not check if i type a phrase. Leave it blank and it says that it did not find E's, it s valid but i want to alert that he didnt enter a string .I will figure that out by myself . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there.

Instead of counting you just display the index of first found E. Try below code

```
function countE() {

    var phrase = prompt("Which phrase would you lke to examine ?");

    if( typeof(phrase) != "string" ) {

        alert("That is not a valid entry!");

        return false;
    }  else {
        var realCountE = 0;
        var efound = false;
        for(var eCount = 0; eCount < phrase.length; eCount++) {

            if( phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'E' || phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'e' ) {
                realCountE++;
            }
        }
        if (realCountE > 0) {
           alert("There are " + realCountE + " E's in \"" + phrase + "\".");
        }
        else {
            var report = confirm("I did not find any E's in your phrase. Would you like to try again?");

            if(report == true) {

                return countE();

            } else {

                alert("Ok maybe next time!");

                return false;
            }
        }


    }
}



countE();
```

Comment: So if the first character is not `e` it will prompt the user? That doesn't seem like what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
var count = 0
for (var eCount 0 through phrase.length)
    if( if( phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'E' || phrase.charAt(eCount) == 'e' )
        count = count + 1;    
if(count == 0)
    print (COULD NOT FIND ANY E's);
else
    print (Found <count> no of E's);
```

Comment: Whats this alien language ? :)

Comment: @lostandfownd I do not know JavaScript. But i could see the problem in your code. In an attempt to create a good enough pseudocode I have apparently ended up writing PseudoJScriptC++. The essence is that you need a separate variable to store your count. Once you have checked all the characters in the string, only then can you comment on the presence and count of E's.

Answer (score -1):

It just checks the first character in your phrase.